# DI with WCF -- Where do I initialize the Windsor Container when using WAS hosting?

Tags: wcf, castle-windsor, was

I was reading an exellent article about [how to use dependency injection with WCF Services](http://javiercrespoalvez.com/2008/05/dependency-injection-in-wcf-services_03.html).
Unfortunately, it only shows how to instantiate and register the Windsor Container in a global.asax file.  I'm looking to use WAS for my hosting so global.asax will not get called.  Does anyone know where I should register the container?  Do I have to extend the WindsorServiceHostFactory an do it in there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% up to date with development of WCF Facility so it may be already there, but if it's not take a look at [this post](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/05/18/SneakViewAtCastlesWCFFacility.aspx) and the comments.

Comment: Thanks.  This was what I was looking for.  Do you think you can help me with another issue I'm having now that I think is a result of the ServiceHostFactory.  

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3615076/getting-the-security-support-provider-interface-sspi-negotiation-failed-when